# Prove that $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy iff $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

**Exercise**

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space and let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences such that $d(x_{n},y_{n}) < \frac{1}{n+1}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy iff $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.

**My attempt**

Suppose that $x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence. This means that
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N})(m\geq n\geq N \Rightarrow  d_{X}(x_{m},x_{n}) < \varepsilon).
\end{align*}

I do not know to proceed, but I think the following inequality may be useful:

\begin{align*}
d_{X}(y_{m},y_{n}) & \leq d_{X}(y_{m},x_{m}) + d_{X}(x_{m},x_{n}) + d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n})\\
\end{align*}

Can anyone suggest me how finish the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start here:

$$\begin{align*}
d_{X}(y_{m},y_{n}) & \leq d_{X}(y_{m},x_{m}) + d_{X}(x_{m},x_{n}) + d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n})\\
\end{align*}$$

- Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, the middle term goes to zero as $n,m \to \infty$
- By assumption, we have that
  $$d(x_{m},y_{m}) < \frac{1}{m+1} \qquad d(x_{n},y_{n}) < \frac{1}{n+1}$$
  and hence $d(x_m,y_m),d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$

Consequently, $d(y_m,y_n) \to 0$ as $m,n \to \infty$.

I'll let you fill in the details as to why it works; this is just the rough sketch proof of the matter.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the limit of the distance between terms of a Cauchy sequence converges to zero?

Comment: It's the definition of a Cauchy sequence. Take $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small; there will always be an $N$ in $\Bbb N$ such that, for $m,n \ge N$, we have $d(x_m,x_n) < \varepsilon$.